# UITableView Scroll to section

Tags: ios, uitableview

Is it possible to scroll to a section instead of a row? If so how?

Btw. I am using a method to remove the floating headers.

Here is the code that I use to move to the selected sections first row.

```
if (self.openSectionIndex != NSNotFound) {
    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:section] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
}
```

this is the code to remove the floating headers

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (self.openSectionIndex != NSNotFound) {
        if (scrollView.contentOffset.y<=DEFAULT_HEADER_HEIGHT&&scrollView.contentOffset.y>=0) {
            scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-scrollView.contentOffset.y, 0, 0, 0);
        } else if (scrollView.contentOffset.y>=DEFAULT_HEADER_HEIGHT) {
            scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-DEFAULT_HEADER_HEIGHT, 0, 0, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

This is somehow what I want but I would rather also show the header.

Right now the header is hidden offscreen in the top.

Comment: Where in the section do you want to scroll to? Your question isn't very clear.

Comment: I want to scroll to the top of the section. Sorry, will make it more clear in a bit.

Comment: And the code you wrote isn't working? It seems pretty straight forward that you scroll to row 0 of that section and place it on top.

Comment: Yes. It works. Just not as I want it to. You see the code scroll's so the row hits the top meaning the header will be pushed above the visible area. I want the header to be where the row is now. not above the screen, but just in top of the screen. :)

Comment: I think this one is the better way:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159821/how-do-i-scroll-a-uitableview-to-a-section-that-contains-no-rows

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of `scrollToRowAtIndexPath`, use `scrollRectToVisible`. You can get precise positioning by passing in a rect with a size that is the same as the table view.

So if you want your header to be positioned exactly at the top, use the header's frame, setting the height to that of the table view, and then pass that to `scrollRectToVisible`.