# Scroll UITableView to a particular section

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want my `UITableView` to scroll to a particular section, how do i achieve this. I have tried a lot of suggestions on SO, and for some strange reason nothing seems to work. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: you have set scroll enable or disable in didselect method

Answer (score 3):

Try by using below lines of code:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        NSInteger Section=3;//Change as required
        NSInteger Row=0;//Change as required

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:Row inSection:Section];

        [tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];

});
```

Edit:

use the following `NSIndexPath` to scroll to a section containing 0 rows:

```
[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:NSNotFound inSection:section]
```

scroll the tableview so the desired section is visible but not necessarily at the top or bottom:

```
CGRect sectionRect = [tableView rectForSection:indexOfSectionToScrollTo];
[tableView scrollRectToVisible:sectionRect animated:YES];
```

to scroll so the section is at the top do this:

```
CGRect sectionRect = [tableView rectForSection:indexOfSectionToScrollTo];
sectionRect.size.height = tableView.frame.size.height;
[tableView scrollRectToVisible:sectionRect animated:YES];
```

Check answer here: [How do I scroll a UITableView to a section that contains no rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159821/how-do-i-scroll-a-uitableview-to-a-section-that-contains-no-rows)

Comment: Yes or where you require to scroll your tableView@TKutal

Comment: Worked great, however i wanted to do this to make sure all my cells are filled with data, but i still have a blank cell at the end of section 1, i added [tableView reloadData] but that didn't work, any suggestion ?

Comment: So basically i need to scroll the tableView a little bit to make sure the data gets added in that cell.

Comment: Sorry but you didn't get my point, i have two sections say A and B, A has 9 rows and B has just 1, when my tableView is scrolled till bottom all rows in section A contains data except the last one, and the section B which is below section A has just one row is filled with data.

Comment: Add some code of tableView delegate methods, so people can help with more detail@TKutal

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this

```
[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:YOUR_INDEX_PATH_OF_SECTION atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES]
```